Rees Algebra Isomorphism $A[xt, yt] \cong A[X, Y] / (yX - xY)$
David Eisenbud's book "The Geometry of Schemes" states the following:
Proposition IV-25: Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $x, y \in A$; let $B$ be the Rees algebra
$$ B = A[xt, yt] \subset A[t].$$
If $x, y \in A$ is a regular sequence, then
$$ B \cong A[X, Y] / (yX - xY)$$
via the map $X \mapsto xt$, $Y \mapsto yt$.
Proof. First we invert $x$ and set $X' = x^{-1}X \in A[x^{-1}][X, Y]$. The element $yX' - Y \in A[x^{-1}][X, Y] = A[x^{-1}][X', Y]$ generates the kernel of the map
$$A[x^{-1}][X', Y] \longrightarrow A[x^{-1}][t],$$
$$X' \mapsto t,$$
$$Y \mapsto yt.$$
Since $(yX' - xY) = (yX - Y)$ in the ring $A[x^{-1}][X, Y]$, it suffices to show that $x$ is a nonzero divisor modulo $yX - xY$ in $A[X, Y]$.
In the second part of the proof he proves that $x$ is a nonzero divisor using Koszuls homology.

Could someone provide the skeleton of the proof
?
Why we invert $x$ in the beginning and why it suffices to show that $x$ is a nonzero divisor modulo $yX - xY$ in $A[X, Y]$ ?
$\bullet$ It seems we invert $x$ is to work with localizations. So we get an isomorphism on the level of the local rings which then somehow gives us the desired isomorphism.

One has a natural surjective map $A[X,Y]/(yX-xY)\to A[xt,yt]$. So, suffices to show this map is injective. Inverting a non-zero divisor if this map is injective, so is the original map.

@Mohan Can you provide some reference for these ? Thank you.
